# Hide all date before the selected date in another JxDatePicker

Tags: java, swing, date

In my case, I have in my program 2 JxDatePicker, the 1st one for recording the date of entry, and 2nd one for recording the date of exit in a Hotel.
I need when I chose a date from the start JxDatePicker to disable all the date before this date in the end JxDatePicker.
something like RangeEvaluator but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you only use **JXDatePicker** for single day selection from a monthly calendar. For interval-selection (start-end), you may want to look into **JXMonthView**

EDIT: May have found you answer
You can not sent a range but you can set upper bounds and lower bounds, which may basically be the same in your case. Try the following example:

```
JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
Calendar calendar = picker.getMonthView().getCalendar();

// set any date to it (for e.g. today)
calendar.setTime(new Date());
picker.getMonthView().setLowerBound(calendar.getTime());

// set it to end when you want
CalendarUtils.endOfWeek(calendar);
calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
picker.getMonthView().setUpperBound(calendar.getTime());
```

Try this example separately, see if it helps.

Comment: So, it is not possible with JXDatePicker?